# lambda in define function not displaying output

Tags: python, lambda

I am new to python. Can you please tell me why am I getting the <function myfunc.. at 0x0000023C9BE08820> error, and not the correct value? please advise

```
def myfunc(a,b):
    o = lambda a,b : a+b
    print(o)

myfunc(5,5)

<function myfunc.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0000023C9BE08820>
```

Comment: That's not an error; it is the value of `o`, exactly what you asked to be printed.

Comment: What's the value you are expecting?

Comment: i want to execute lambda function to give me answer 10 (when a=4 and b=6)

Comment: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/03/what-are-lambda-functions-in-python/

Comment: Well, if you want to execute the function, then you need to write code that does that. Just like if you wanted to execute a function. If you wrote `myfunc` you would see the value of `myfunc`, not the result of calling `myfunc`, because you didn't call it. Lambdas are the same; after all they are just another (less capable) syntax for functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not giving "`o`" any args in `print(o)` so it's returning (printing) the lambda function.

```
def myfunc(a,b):
    o = lambda a,b : a+b
    print(o(a,b))

 myfunc(5,5)
```

returns:

```
10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could've used an *immediate invocation*:

```
def myfunc(a,b):
    o = (lambda a,b : a+b)(a,b)
    print(o)

myfunc(5,5)
```

The above is just for illustration purposes. It does not make sense to program this way.